# Json.net deserialization in Web Api with Autofac injection

Tags: json.net, asp.net-web-api2, autofac

Json.net allows to provide custom ContractResolver when deserializing objects from json:
[Deserialize with dependency injection](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeWithDependencyInjection.htm) and [Json.NET 6.0 Release 4](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2014/08/04/json-net-6-0-release-4-json-merge-dependency-injection)

In order to resolve dependencies root container has to be passed to AutofacContractResolver object when Autofac is configured. 
However it makes impossible to resolve InstancePerRequest dependencies because of not matching scope (DependencyResolutionException: No scope with a Tag matching
'AutofacWebRequest' is visible from the scope in which the instance
was requested... Is thrown)

Is there any way of configuring this custom resolver which allows resolving InstancePerRequest dependencies?

Comment: Is there a specific reason these dependencies need to be `InstancePerRequest`? Why doesn't it hold true when deserializing?

Comment: Yes, I need them to be InstancePerRequest because I need to access current HttpRequestMessage. When deserializing (although it happens for each request) current scope is 'root'.

Comment: So the deserialized objects don't need to access `HttpRequestMessage`? When does `HttpRequestMessage` need to be accessed - can you provide a code-example?

Comment: The deserialized object itself doesn't need it, but one of its dependencies needs it later in controller action.

Comment: ok. For me this sounds like that dependency doesn't need to be `InstancePerRequest`. Which should solve your problem.

Comment: Unfortunately if any of component dependencies needs InstancePerRequest scope then I can't resolve this component in root scope (as per http://docs.autofac.org/en/stable/faq/per-request-scope.html#troubleshooting-per-request-dependencies)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105777/discussion-between-batterybackupunit-and-wziska).